# How to get rid of the linked lines

Tags: interface, import

[image]I've imported my dxf file in Blender.
But I see every object has a linked line to the origin point.
I'd like to know what this means and if I can get rid of it. Thanks!

Comment: They're Relationship lines. You can disable their visibility by unchecking the Relationship Lines option on the Viewport Overlays menu.

Comment: here the visual of Johns explanation: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqTM2.png

Comment: Same as above but with cues: https://i.imgur.com/Ka9XDt4.png